# Can CoreData attributes be extended?

Tags: ios, swift, attributes

I want to add an enum to all of my entities attributes. For example, if I have a Product entity with a Name and a Price attribute, I want to be able to add something that can quickly identify if Name is a "public" attribute or a "private" attribute and then the same for the Price attribute.

The enums will always stay the same once the entity is initialized and never stored with each records, only in the entity.

Here is what I'm trying to achieve with a function:

func returnShareableAttribute(product.name) -> enumShareable {
}

Is this possible and if so could someone guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

[How to extend core data entity classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28291182/how-to-extend-core-data-entity-classes)

I believe you are looking for this

Comment: Actually no. I don't want to subclass an NSManagedObject, I want to add an ENUM the Entities attributes. In other words, I need each attributes to tell me what type of Shareable (enum class that has 3 enums possibilities => .privatedAttribute, .publicAttribute, .shareableAttribute it is.